# Logging PHP SERVER variables to database

Tags: php, mysql, logging, http-headers

I plan to log all [PHP $_SERVER variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) which are not static across all requests (like SERVER_SIGNATURE), to a database table. I have two questions:

1) Is there a max length of fields like HTTP_ACCEPT, etc? I am using the following structure. Its not optimized and not the best, but just a starting indication. Any links to where I can find max lenghths for some/all of the variabels will be useful.

2) Is it wise to store PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW? Can this result in security issues? On the other hand, can these fields ever be even remotely useful in analyzing traffic?

Note:

1) Right now, I just want to log everything I can that can even remotely help me in analyzing traffic to my sites in future.

2) For some things, I have assumed practical limits (like I know I will not be creating path names on server more than hundred character long etc). However, I want to play safe and especially on fields that depend on the client requests.

Relevant part of the table looks like:

```
`PHP_SELF` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SERVER_PROTOCOL` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`REQUEST_METHOD` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`REQUEST_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL,
`QUERY_STRING` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
`DOCUMENT_ROOT` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_ACCEPT` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_CONNECTION` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_HOST` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_REFERER` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
`HTTP_USER_AGENT` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
`HTTPS` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`REMOTE_ADDR` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`REMOTE_PORT` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`SCRIPT_FILENAME` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`SERVER_PORT` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`SCRIPT_NAME` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`REQUEST_URI` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
`PHP_AUTH_DIGEST` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`PHP_AUTH_USER` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`PHP_AUTH_PW` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`AUTH_TYPE` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`PATH_INFO` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
`ORIG_PATH_INFO` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: What is the purpose of all this logging?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Despite your earlier advice I keep wasting time with all this stuff :). To be honest, I have not yet figured out a comprehensive logging solution, that will be my own (not google analytics etc), will not use Disk I/O at all (atleast not at the time of serving the request - I want the logging to happen as a low priority process after the request is served) and something, that I can analyze using my own algorithms when the time comes.

Comment: So, you don't know yet. I am afraid it's impossible to answer your question then

Comment: Huh? I am already using a system in which I just append the array and dump it in mysql as a delayed insert. I am now just going a step further to clean it and store as a separate field. Your comment is not helpful at all.

Comment: I asked you what is purpose of all this logging. You can't answer it.

Comment: No offense, but: I answered what is the purpose of all this logging, you couldn't interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

The commonly accepted maximum length (in de facto use in Apache httpd, for example) for a given header is 8k. (8192 bytes)

The security issues with storing this data would be the same as storing any user-provided data. Use parameter binding (like as offered by PDO). Don't simply count on escaping the strings.

There are other performance considerations with your database schema. You might consider changing the columns to type TEXT because of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html):

(*Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes [..] BLOB and TEXT columns are counted at [9-12] bytes per column toward the row size limit because the contents of these columns are stored separately from the rest of the row*)

Comment: you might also consider a document-oriented "NoSQL" solution for logging this sort of data, because of the schemaless nature (think CouchDB / MongoDB), but that's outside the scope of this question I think. :)

Comment: Thanks for nice info. I guess 8K is the total header length? That perhaps will not give good idea about individual fields. Regarding user-provided data - what I mean't is is it a breach of security for user credentials? Are these unencrypted passwords?  And lastly, after reading your link, I will change the types to text.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Is it wise to store PHP_AUTH_USER
>   and PHP_AUTH_PW? Can this result in
>   security issues? On the other hand,
>   can these fields ever be even remotely
>   useful in analyzing traffic?

I'd suggest not to store the `PHP_AUTH_PW?`, except for analizing the user passwords for personal preferences, it does not help you in any way. BUT it might cause big trouble if someone finds out that you save this kind of data (in case that you are not allowed to (which can be the case)) or if another one gets access to your database somehow and uses those user/pwds to get access to the accounts.

PHP_AUTH_USER might be of some relevance. And storing the users loginname alone does not pose a security problem.

Comment: Thanks. This very much solves my doubt for point 2. And you figured my intention perfectly - I was thinking *maybe* I could analyze personal preference this way but I think it is risky.